Connection to aurora database does not work from local java application
I am currently using org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.9 to connect to my aurora database cluster. I need to update this dependency now, but since mariadb dropped the support for aurora databases from version 3.x, I guess I have to use the AWS JDBC Driver instead. So I followed the github guide to use that driver, but either the documentation is really bad or I am just too stupid to use it correctly. I added the dependency software.amazon.jdbc:aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper, updated the driver from org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver to software.amazon.jdbc.Driver and changed the jdbc url from jdbc:mysql:aurora//my-cluster.aws.cloud:3306/databaseName to jdbc:aws-wrapper:mysql//my-cluster.aws.cloud:3306/databaseName. With that configuration I get the error No database found to handle jdbc:aws-wrapper:mysql//my-cluster.aws.cloud:3306, which is actually thrown by flyway. So I guess either a dependency is missing or my configuration is wrong. Can someone help?

what doc are you referencing

@smac2020 https://github.com/awslabs/aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper/blob/main/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/UsingTheJdbcDriver.md#aws-jdbc-driver-for-mysql-migration-guide

Okay, I think I found the answer. So flyway checks the jdbc string and looks for the correct flyway plugin to handle the database migration. Since there is no plugin for the jdbc string that begins with jdbc:aws-wrapper, flyway crashes. This basically means that you cannot use aws jdbc wrapper together with flyway.
But even in tools like DBeaver the aws jdbc wrapper does not work together with the mariadb driver. So instead I am now using the mysql driver com.mysql:mysql-connector-j which works together with the aws jdbc wrapper and even works on its own without using the aws jdbc driver. Since I want to use flyway, I cannot use the aws jdbc driver (as before mentioned), so I am now just using the mysql driver to connect to aurora databases.
